# ember-django-adapter code sample

Tags: python, django, ember.js, django-rest-framework

I am trying to write an Ember CLI application that talks to a REST api developed using Django-Rest-Framework.
I tried to ember-django-adapter as my data adpater for the ember application, however I cannot find a sample code on how to configure and write a model to use this data adapter. Can someone please help.
This is the EDA code https://github.com/dustinfarris/ember-django-adapter.

Also all I did on the ember app side is to create new app, and change the config as recommended here http://dustinfarris.com/ember-django-adapter/configuring/:

```
if (environment === 'development') {
    ENV.APP.API_HOST = 'http://localhost:8000';
  }

  if (environment === 'production') {
    ENV.APP.API_HOST = 'https://api.myproject.com';
    ENV.APP.API_NAMESPACE = 'v2';
  }
```

but this doc, doesn't say how to configure the data adapter for ember! Please let me know if there is a way to make ember js and django-rest-framework talk.

Thanks.

Comment: That's all you need to do.  What, exactly, is not working for you?

Comment: Well when I try to get the data from Ember JS, no records!!!

Comment: Which store method in Ember are you using to retrieve the records?  In the network tab, are there any issues?  Is DRF responding to the requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before using Ember-data, I would suggest you to create a basic Ajax call using jQuery.

- **Step 1** (basic AJAX call with jQuery):

*route.js*:

```
model() {
    return Ember.$.getJSON("/api/v1/foo");
}
```

- **Step 2** (Create the model `foo` with the correct adapter using `ActiveModelAdapter`):

*models/foo.js*:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
 var attr = DS.attr;
 export default DS.Model.extend({
     bar: attr('string'),
     isTest: attr('boolean')
 });
```

*adapters/foo.js*:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
 import config from 'shippo-frontend/config/environment';
 import Ember from 'ember';
 export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
   namespace: 'api/v1',
   host: apiUrl 
});
```

- **Step 3** (replace your jQuery call by the Ember-data call):

*route.js*:

```
model() {
  return this.get('store').findAll('foo');
}
```

- **Notes:**

  - `active-model-adapter` allows you to transform your snake_keys into camelCaseKeys. https://github.com/ember-data/active-model-adapter
  - If you need to do other modifications on the data coming from Django, create a `serializers/foo.js` and play around with the payload.